# conda export env from bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, virtualenv, miniconda

I came up with the following bash script to export my `conda-env` to a file.

**run.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
option=$1
case "$option" in
    -e|--export)
        conda env export -n myenv | grep -v "^prefix: " > ../setup/env.yaml
        shift
        ;;
        esac
done
```

the line `conda env export -n myenv | grep -v "^prefix: " > ../setup/env.yaml` works as expected when executed in command line. But on executing `./run.sh -e`, the `env.yaml` looks like,

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - defaults
```

Seeking help to fix this. Thanks.

Edit: already tried the string and `eval` method from the link (https://stephencowchau.medium.com/simple-bash-script-to-export-all-conda-virtual-environments-2e337cd9480), which also yields the same result as my script.

Edit2: This seems to work in Linux machines. But not working in WSL in windows.

Comment: Not sure, but try running bash in login mode, i.e., change shebang to `#!/usr/bin/bash -l`.

Comment: @merv, No luck with login mode

Comment: I still believe it's a user problem - i.e., `conda` is executed under a different user so that the `envs_dirs` is not defined as it is when you have shell session. The `conda env export` command will always output something, even if the `-n` named env doesn't exist. It might be more reliable to identify the env via a `-p` (path/prefix), or do something to ensure that `conda config --show envs_dirs` gives the same result at CLI and in the script, e.g., manually set `CONDA_ENVS_DIRS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following lines in the start of script fixed the issue

```
CONDA_PATH=$(conda info | grep -i 'base environment' | awk '{print $4}')
source $CONDA_PATH/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```